# Converting danish double to string with multiple "." separator [ Thousand ]

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert number in `string` format to `double`. It can be either *English* culture or *Danish* culture. Here is the code I'm trying

```
public static double ToDoubleOrDefault(this string value)
{
    var doubleValue = default(double);

    var danishCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
    var englishCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    if (double.TryParse(value, 
                        NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                        englishCultureInfo, 
                        out doubleValue))
    {
        return doubleValue;
    }
    else if (double.TryParse(value, 
                             NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                             danishCultureInfo, 
                             out doubleValue))
    {
        return doubleValue;
    }
    return doubleValue;
}
```

It works fine if till the *Danish* number have *more than one* `"."` *separator*.

Eg: **"1.908.746"**

Is there a way were it can be done?

Comment: Try this: `danishCultireInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "."`

Comment: How will you differentiate whether `1.000` is a one with three zeroes, or one thousand? Same goes for `1,000`.

Comment: I don't know much about danish doubles.  Is it similar to double dutch?  Perhaps you could list out a few expected inputs and outputs so that we can see all the edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`

```
public static double ToDoubleOrDefault(this string value) {
  var doubleValue = default(double);

  // We don't have to create new instances (new CultureInfo()...)
  var danishCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK");
  var englishCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

  if (double.TryParse(value, 
                      NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                      englishCultureInfo, 
                      out doubleValue)) 
    return doubleValue;
  else if (double.TryParse(value, 
                           NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                           danishCultureInfo, 
                           out doubleValue)) 
    return doubleValue;
  else if (double.TryParse(value, 
                           NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                           englishCultureInfo, 
                           out doubleValue)) 
    return doubleValue;
  else if (double.TryParse(value, 
                           NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                           danishCultureInfo, 
                           out doubleValue)) 
    return doubleValue;

  return doubleValue;
}
```

So we try treating given `string` as

1. English floating point without thousand separator, e.g. `123456789.1`
2. Danish floating point without thousand separator, e.g. `123456789,1`
3. English floating point with thousand separator, e.g. `123,456,789.1`
4. Danish floating point with thousand separator, e.g. `123.456.789,1`

Please, notice that we have an *ambiguity* here: `123.456` is `123.456` (English, since `.` is a *decimal* separator) and `123456` (Danish, since `.` is a *thousand* separator)

Answer (score 0):

This way you should be fine:

```
string strNumber = "1.908.746";
double number = double.Parse(strNumber.Replace(".", ""));
```

Comment: But the number also can be in normal format, ie, 123.22 with .22 in decimal part @Marco

Comment: Sorry but then you have some kind of problem in your system.

Comment: If you are separating 3 digits with a `.` you should use `,` to separate decimals or viceversa

Comment: actually the number is input from user, it can be in danish culture, but not always

Comment: And what if your user does 1.908.746.123 but the .123 are decimals?

Comment: From my point of view, you should limit which characters the user will use into the application. For example many banks use comma as decimals separator to avoid such cases.